# Next Button after correct answers on quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been handed some code at work and told to fix it (even though I have about a month of JavaScript/HTML experience).

Here's the deal:

The website is a quiz with three buttons. There are 8 questions total, each question is on it's own page. Right now the "next" button to proceed is hidden until all of the correct answers are selected (some of the questions have more than one correct answer). What I want to change is how the button is presented. Two problems 1) if all of the correct answers are selected, the button is shown, even if an incorrect answer is still selected. 2) rather than have the button appear when the correct answers are selected, I want the button to change from grey (disabled) to blue (enabled).

The code I've been handed is a MESS. I can't seem to find anywhere in the JQuery where any of the functions for the next button are. All I have is this:

```
<!---NEXT BUTTON--->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="correct1 box" style="border:none">
    <div class="correct2 box" style="border:none">
    <div class="correct3 box" style="border:none">
<nav class="mainmenu"><p>
    <a href="#page2" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Next</a></p></nav>
  </div>
```

In this example, the next button will appear on the page once the correct box 1, correct box 2, and correct box 3 are ALL checked (regardless of order).

To make it ore tricky, once you select one of the options, a feedback box appears telling you whether or not your selection is correct or incorrect (and why).

I don't even know where to begin...to the best of my knowledge that's the ONLY code for any sort of navigation on the page. Since I'm working on a deadline, completely scrapping the code for the entire page isn't an option (although believe me, with how messy it is, I wish that was an option).

Any suggestions on where to look in the files for code? Any suggestions on what to use to make the two things that I'm looking to do work?

Comment: Could you set up the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) so that we can look at it and help you find where to start?

Comment: This really isn't enough to go on. You're going to have to find the current JavaScript that determines whether an answer is right/wrong, then build off of that to achieve what you're trying to do. Is there any more code you can post?